# How do you assign certain permissions to a single user without using the roles?

Tags: permissions, drupal-7

Adding permissions to a role enables the given permission to all users in that role by default; this is something I want to avoid. 
I want to be able to set permissions like "Booking: View own Bookings" at user level and not the role level.

Is there a module that already does this, or can someone give me some possible approaches or pseudo code of some kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's the [User Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/user_permissions) module.

> User Permissions provides an interface for giving additional permissions to individual users without the need to assign them to a special role. When this module is enabled, users with the 'administer permissions' permission can access the 'User Permissions' tab on each user's account.